# TypeScript/ESLint doesn't pick up invalid function name as compile error

Tags: typescript, eslint

I encountered a runtime error in my lambda function, and I'm trying to understand why TypeScript or ESLint was not able to pick it up as a compile error.

I had a typo in a function name (``` any`` ```) in a block of code that looks like:

```js
export function getHeaderLinkValidationSchema() {
  const { stage } = process.env;

  return Joi.object()
    .keys({
      "header": stage === "prod" ? Joi.any()``.forbidden() : Joi.number()optional(),
    })
    .required()
    .unknown();
}
```

Tests for this function pass, because the tests run with a `stage` that is not `"prod"`.

Is that something ESLint or TypeScript should be able to detect as a compile error?

Comment: Presumably because it could be a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates). `Joi.number()optional()` certainly wouldn't work though.

Comment: That particular typo could be a tagged template, but if I try with `anyy` it's the same  thing. No compiler error.

Comment: You'll have to give a [mre] then, is `Joi` typed?